# Java Regex Capture String After Specific String

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to capture the "456456" in

```
Status: Created | Ref ID: 456456 | Name: dfg  | Address: 123
```

with no whitespaces

I got a working regex and later find out that java does not support \K.

```
\bRef ID:\s+\K\S+
```

Is there any way to get support for \K?
or a different regex?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with captured group: `\bRef ID:\s+(\S+)`

Comment: From what I know, you can even use `(?<=Ref ID:\s+)\S+` (as Android patterns use an ICU regex flavor). However, capturing is what you need.

Comment: @anubhava that is capturing Ref ID and the number. I am trying to get just the number after Ref ID.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i get an invalid regex on (?<=Ref ID:\s+)\S+

Comment: Thank you, so that means the bug was fixed. And what about `(?<=Ref ID:\s{1,1000})\S+`?

Comment: @HappyPoofySquirrel: No, look again. Rounds brackets make it a captured group and `(\S+)` is the value being captured

Comment: if you know what to use as boundary, why don't you replace the matching string with the same word boundary. So in essence , you would replace "Ref ID:  " in "Ref ID: 456456" and the result will be "456456" . Then you can Omit \K.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to get support for \K?

You could conceivably use a third-party regex library that provides it.  You cannot get it in the standard library's `Pattern` class.

> or a different regex?

I'm uncertain whether you recognize that "capture" is a technical term in the regex space that bears directly on the question.  It is indeed the usual way to go about what you describe, but the regex you present doesn't do any capturing at all.  To capture the desired text with a Java regex, you want to put parentheses into the pattern, around the part whose match you want to capture:

```
\bRef ID:\s+(\S+)
```

In case of a successful match, you access the captured group via the `Matcher`'s `group()` method:

```
String s = "Status: Created | Ref ID: 456456 | Name: dfg  | Address: 123";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bRef ID:\\s+(\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String refId = matcher.group(1);
    // ...
}
```

Note that you need to use `matcher.find()` with that regex, not `matcher.matches()`, because the latter tests whether the whole string matches, whereas the former tests only whether there is a substring that matches.

Comment: More (flavor-agnostic) information on regular expression [groups/capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying some things for me. The regex you provided solved my problem. And your explanation gave me a much better understanding .A+